# How to get jar file name by Module in Java 9?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

For example I have `somefile-0.1.jar` jar file which contains JPMS module. Besides, I have a reference `Module somemodule` to this module.

How to get jar file name by Module (using `somemodule` reference)? I've examined Module API but didn't find a way to do it.

Comment: Could you clarify the `somefile-0.1.jar` would be used on the class path or module path?

Comment: @nullpointer Module path. But of course it would be nice it solution supported both paths.

Comment: On module path does `module.getResourceAsStream("module-info.class")` help?

Comment: @nullpointer But what about automatic modules that don't have `module-info.class`?

Comment: One relation there could possibly be is that their name is derived from the name of the jar itself. The deriving logic probably can help to lookup reverse.

Comment: Whats the use case for this problem by the way, I couldn't think of any where you would want to not know the source and derive it from a module you would be using in the code?

Comment: @nullpointer We have all our applications on OSGi. Now we decided to move to JPMS. So we check different things which we need to see how they can work. In OSGi it is Bundle.getLocation().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no guarantee that module was loaded from a modular JAR. In any case, I think this is close to what you are looking for:

```
Module m = ...
ModuleLayer layer = m.getLayer();
if (layer != null) {
    ModuleReference mref = layer.configuration()
            .findModule(m.getName())
            .map(ResolvedModule::reference)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("should not happen"));
}
```

Comment: when can the layer be null? why a null check there?

Comment: @nullpointer From `Module#getLayer`'s documentation: "Returns the module layer that contains this module or null if this module is not in a module layer. A module layer contains named modules and therefore this method always returns null when invoked on an unnamed module.

Dynamic modules are named modules that are generated at runtime. A dynamic module may or may not be in a module layer."